# Child's object undefined in sample code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling my chain promise function in such a way.
But encounter problem XXX is not defined as follow.
How can I solve it?

Note that `console.log(res.coords.latitude)` does return value but the function throws undefined

```js
function getGPSLocation(geolocationOptions) {
    
}

function initMap(lat, lng) {
 console.log(lat);
 console.log(lng);
}

var initMap = function (res) {
    console.log(res.coords.latitude); // res.coords.latitude has value
    initMap(res.coords.latitude, res.coords.longitude); 
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

    return res;
};

getGPSLocation()
    .then(initMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you share the full code please?

Comment: is initMap function a recursive one?

Comment: JS doesn't support method overloading. It simply take the latest method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initMapTest(lat, lng) {
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lng);
}

var initMap = function (res) {
    console.log(res.coords.latitude); // res.coords.latitude has value
    initMapTest(res.coords.latitude, res.coords.longitude);

    return res;
};
```